# Glympse API Linker Error for iOS

Tags: glympse

I am unable to compile the Glympse API for iOS due to 4 duplicate symbol errors in the framework.  Like the example projects, I only import the GlympseLite.h header in my .pch file.  Is anyone else having this issue?

One of the duplicate symbols is: __ZN7Glympse15ControlsFactory9showAboutERKNS_1OINS_12IGlympseLiteEEERKNS1_INS_8IGlympseEEE

Answer (score 1):

How did you add GlympseKitLite into your project? Could you provide exact steps. 
Which XCode version are you using? 
Is there anything special about compiler/linker flags in your project? 
Is it brand new or existing project? 
Were you able to build sample projects provided with SDK?

I just confirmed that it compiles fine in a brand new projects. Here are the steps I followed:

- Created new iOS project.
- Dragged `GlympseKitLite.embeddedframework` (from SDK package) to `Frameworks`.
- Added all required standard frameworks (`CFNetwork, libz, CoreLocation, AddressBook, Security, EventKit, MapKit, MessageUI`).
- Added import entry to PCH file.
- Called `Glympse::LiteFactory::createGlympse(...);`

In the mean time you can try the following. Set `C Language Dialect`, `C++ Language Dialect` and `C++ Standard Library` to `Compiler Default`. Let me know, if it helps.

Comment: I finally figured it out.  After looking over the linker flags, it turns out -all_load caused it.  It's reproducible on the demo projects.  I'll check over my other libraries but I don't believe it's a requirement for my project so I should be OK without it.  Thanks.

Comment: Better yet, I'm now using -force_load on the library that required it & everything's compiling now.